# Причине конкретной по, btrfs от ext4 отличается производительностью на запись низкой очень?

Tags: linux, память, ssd

Памяти блок SSD 128 GB.
Записи скорость btrfs на, 500-1000 кб/с
Записи скорость ext4 на, 8 мб/с
При этом чтение одинаковое.
Монтирования параметры были стандартными (кроме sync), дополнительно убедился об не работе дефрагментации на лету, поставил дополнительно режим -o ssd, при том поддержки определят автоматически. Менял режим сжатия на включено и выключено, производительность не изменило.

Причина происходящего. правка: + КаКова?

Comment: Это что за йода писал?

Comment: googe translate?

Comment: мне кажется ссд мертв. 477 MB/s скорость записи на нормальном аппарате

Comment: Он не мёртв. Пропущено ext4 работает быстрее. Вместо занятия категорией моей, они обсуждают правила написания. Может это вы делали btrfs по жопному?

Comment: Дохмий какой-то, что ли завелся?

Comment: @avp а может он переводит свой вопрос на английский а потом обратно на русский? С "делали btrfs по жопному" посмеялся.

Comment: Вы объявили войну за слово BTR, правилам написания, вместо скорости низкой

Comment: @Anonim,  а на обычных HDD как они себя ведут?

Comment: На обычных тестил нет зато в tmpfs производительность 34 мб/с вместо 300 мбс/с подобно для ext4